# MapHttpRoute with custom HttpMessageHandler

Tags: c#, http, routes, asp.net-web-api

So I'm having a troubles getting the route to work properly after the messagehandler has finished.
Error that shows up are:
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

this is what I got so far:

http://localhost:51077/api/v1/project/getprojects?apikey=123456

```
        // all actions under /project routes require authentication
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "ProjectApi",
            "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{apikey}",
            new { apikey = RouteParameter.Optional },
            null,
            HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                      new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), 
                      new DelegatingHandler[]{new BasicAuthHandler(config)}));

        // all routes requires an api key
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiKeyHandler());
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

---

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/ProjectController")]
public class ProjectController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getprojects")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProjects()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

So, all calls will first be checked if they have an ApiKey included to be able to connect (ApiKeyHandler) Then a popup appears and asks for username and password(BasicAuthHandler). If the log in is a success then it should be forwarded to the getprojects method under /project...

ApiKey is checked, username/password popup appears and is granted but then the error above comes and the route seems to be to invalid. I've tried different ways to get this to work but it seems I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED

Just comment this line out and it works

```
[Route("getprojects")] // <--- COMMENT/REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Any ideas to why this was causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't replicate in my test that I tried at my end. It seems you have different names given to your controller in your RoutePrefix attribute. According to the request Url given:

> http://localhost:51077/api/v1/project/getprojects?apikey=123456

RoutePrefix attibute on ProjectController class should look like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Project")]
```

Comment: I changed it to Project instead. Still works :)
However, if I add the line
[Route("getprojects")]

to the method GetProjects the issues pops up again. Even if the route is empty aka: [Route("")]